# apt-offline only install specific packages and don't upgrade/update

Tags: apt, package-management

`apt-offline` seems like a great tool for installing packages on a non-networked machine.

However, I'm having a problem where it does an `update/upgrade` instead of just installing the packages that I specified. Is there a way to force it to only install the packages selected (and their dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/blob/d3663ff94d4775c3399d04a2b2749f085711e630/apt-offline.8) of apt-offline you have to follow this sequence:

```
Sequence  1:  The following set of commands, when run in sequence, will
   update a disconnected machine.

          apt-offline set update.sig --update

          (Generate the required data needed to update the  APT  database.
          Should be run on the disconnected machine)

          apt-offline get update.sig --bundle update.zip

          (Download  the  required data needed to update the APT database.
          Should be run on a machine with internet connectivity)

          apt-offline install update.zip

          (Installs the data needed to update the APT database. Should  be
          run on the disconnected machine)


Sequence  2: With successful completion of Sequence 1, the APT database
   on the disconnected machine will be up-to-date. Now, the following  set
   of commands, when run in sequence, will upgrade a disconnected machine.

          apt-offline set upgrade.sig --upgrade

          (Genereate  the  required  data needed to upgrade the upgradable
          packages. Should be run on the disconnected machine)

          apt-offline get upgrade.sig --bundle upgrade.zip

          (Download the required data needed  to  upgrade  the  upgradable
          packages. Should be run on a machine with internet connectivity)

          apt-offline install upgrade.zip

          (Installs  the  data  needed to upgrade the upgradable packages.
          Should be run on the disconnected machine)

After completion of
          Sequence 1 and Sequence 2  in  order,  further  running  apt-get
          upgrade will result in 0 bytes of additional download.
```